# Strange behaviour with performance on data retrieval

Tags: .net, performance, entity-framework

I have a MVC3 wep application that connects to a WCF service to get it's needed data. This WCF service get's the data from a MS SQL 2008 R2 database using Entity Framework 5 Code First.

I have one call that gets data from the database, that has a lot of includes, but the data in the database is quite small. I have added a Stopwatch in the method that retrieves the data and logs how much time the actual data retrieval takes.

On my machine when I start the service up fresh, the first time that method is run it takes around 3500ms. I guess this is because EF does something to check database consistency and so on. All calls after this takes 10-40 ms and is perfectly acceptable.

On the real server however, all calls regardless if it's the first call or not takes 4000-5000ms, and that is unbearable. Calls to other methods that retrieve data shows the same symptoms, and is extremly slow on the server, but fast on my machine.

The only differences between my machine and the server that I can see are:

My machine runs Windows7, has 8Gb memory, .NET framework 4.5 installed, MS SQL Server 2008
The server is a virtual machine runs Windows Server 2008 R2, has 4 Gb of RAM dedicated, .NET framework 4 installed and runs MS SQL Server 2008 R2.

Anyone knows why the data retrieval performance is so extremly slow on the server but not on my machine?

Comment: Is your WCF service hosted in IIS? If yes, check how often is your AppDomain recycled - each application restart means new initialization.

Comment: No, my WCF serice is self hosted inside a windows service. I also tried it selfhosted inside a console app, but the same differences still remain

Comment: Only more thing I just checked now, is that without any of the includes, the data retrieval takes 7ms on my machine, also for the first data retrieval. And stays at around 4-5ms after the first

Comment: My first chunch was that the indexes was messed up, but the indexes are the same on both my machine and the server (and both databases are created by EF Code First, so the structure at least should be indentical.

Comment: So wait ... you have a local database and a database on a server?

Comment: @ryan1234 - Yes, when I tested this now I have a local database on my developer machine where it goes fast, and also a local database on the virtual server where it goes very slow.

Comment: Did you ever find a cause for this? I'm experiencing the same issue...

Comment: @DanielLidström - Actually, I never did and I'm afraid we're looking at a EF bug here. What I ended up doing was making it semi-manual using EFs dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<T>("add sql here"); this performs the query, and will cast the resultset to IEnumerable<T> for you. But you have to handle all includes manually as seperate queries. So a bit more work, uglier code, but the speed problems are gone. And I only had to do this for the one query where I faced the problems.

Comment: @ØyvindKnobloch-Bråthen Thanks for the tip, that's worth trying for me as well.